# fetchColumn vs columnCount

Tags: php, mysql, sql

colsulta `SELECT` que debe devolver un solo resgistro si existe,

lo valido con

`if ($stmtStore->fetchColumn ()==0){...}` y el redultado es `true`

y la valido con

`if ($stmtStore->columnCount ()==0){...}` y el resultado es `false`

segun las definiciones

*columnCount* — Devuelve el número de columnas de un conjunto de resultados.

*fetchColumn* — Devuelve una única columna de la siguiente fila de un conjunto de resultados.

No entiendo la descripcion

Lo que necesito es validar si el `SELECT` me devuelve la fila o no, ya he utilizado la funcion `fetchColumn` en el desarrollo de una aplicacion y me entran dudas.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Para validar si existen registros lo correcto es usar `fetchColumn`.

La clave es la forma en que escribas la consulta. Este tipo de validaciones se hacen contando el total de filas, algo así:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM tabla;
```

Esa consulta devolverá una única columna `total` con el total de filas encontradas, ahora puedes usar `fetchColumn()`:

```
$totalFilas=$stmt->fetchColumn();

if ($totalFilas > 0){
    //Hay registros
}
```

En cuanto a `columnCount`, como su nombre lo indica, es para obtener el número de columnas de un resultado. En el caso de más arriba, devolverá siempre `1`, si `PDOStatement` existe, independientemente de que haya filas o no, porque lo que hace es contar el total de columnas, no el total de filas.

Está claramente explicado en el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.columncount.php):

> #### Valores devueltos
>
> Devuelve el número de columnas del conjunto de resultados representado
>   por el objeto `PDOStatement`, **incluso si el conjunto de resultados
>   está vacío**. Si no hubiera conjunto de resultados,
>   `PDOStatement::columnCount()` devuelve 0.

Cuidado de no confundirte con esta afirmación: *Si no hubiera conjunto de resultados, `PDOStatement::columnCount()` devuelve 0.* Eso no se refiere a si no hubiera filas en el resultado, sino a que `PDOStatement` sea `NULL` o `FALSE` por no haberse creado correctamente o por haberlo cerrado antes de invocar al método.